# Get updated location of object.x and object.y with Physics Engine

Tags: coronasdk

Hi I'm new to Corona SDK. I hope someone can help me out.

I have an object (called furry) dropping from the sky, using the physics engine of the Corona SDK.

When this object Furry is half way the screen I would like to play a sound effect (wee.mp3).

I'm trying to update furry.x and furry.y to control for the updated location. But I'm not sure how to do this as the physics engine updates the location based on gravity.

I hope the code below is sufficient to help me.

```
centerX = display.contentWidth * .5
centerY = display.contentHeight * .5

local furry = display.newImage("flurry.png")
furry.x = centerX-300
furry.y = centerY-1000
physics.addBody(furry, "dynamic", physicsData:get("flurry"))


if furry.x == centerX then
    audio.play(wee)
end
```

So how can I get after the game has started the updated locations (x, y) of my object Furry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Runtime Listener `enterFrame` to detect the object location see the code below

```
physics = require("physics")
physics.start()

centerX = display.contentWidth * .5
centerY = display.contentHeight * .5
local function listener( event )


local furry = display.newCircle(10,10,10)
furry.x = math.random(1, display.contentWidth)
furry.y = 10
physics.addBody(furry, "dynamic")

local function removeObject()

    if furry.y > centerY then
        furry:removeSelf()
        Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", removeObject)
    end

end


Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", removeObject)

end

timer.performWithDelay( 500, listener ,0)
```

Comment: Sorry this doesn't seem to work. I checked the if statement by changing it into < and then it starts playing the sound effect (as the start position of the object is already <). But when I change it into == or > it doesnt work.

Comment: == will be tough to make work since the object would have to be exactly at exact place to trigger it and with physics, it may be at a fractional value and never exactly match exactly.  The > should work as long as you put in a flag to only check it once..

Comment: yes RobMiracle is right it's hard to get the exact value of the condition if it will return fractional value you might need to use logical operators.

Comment: Hi @RobMiracle, thanks for responding this makes sense. Still makes me wonder, is there a way to trigger an event when an object is eg half way the screen while applying physics to it with gravity. For now I used a perform.timerWithDelay to somehow time it. But I would assume there should be a more elegant way